# How to sort an html table column values based on Date values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, css-tables

I am working with some stored database (EF) values and displaying them in an html table for generating a report (via API request).
This is how i am calling the variables

```
    foreach (var obj in meeting.Where(n => n.ParentID == vmContent.ParentID))
                {
                    Compliance = Compliance + obj.Compliance;
                    DirectivesList = DirectivesList + obj.MeetingTypeName + obj.MeetingDate.ToDatePickerFormat() + obj.Directives;
                }
```

And this is how i am writing the code for HTML tables

```
            <td style='font-family:&quot;Bookman Old Style&quot;,serif;vertical-align: top;border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; padding:5px;width:170px'>
            <p><span style='font-size:11pt'>" + DirectivesList + @"</span></p>
            </td>
            <td style='font-family:&quot;Bookman Old Style&quot;,serif;vertical-align: top;border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; padding:5px;width:170px'>
            <p>" + Compliance + @"</p>
            </td>
```

This is the way my table columns are appearing
[Table Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXyx.png)

For me, all else is working fine only problem being, I want to sort these values based on the meeting date which is included inside the Directives' List. Any ideas how to do that without using queries? **Can I sort these values based on Meeting Date using HTML/CSS/Javascript, without using any button?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order your meetings in your code behind.

```
var meetings = meeting.Where(n => n.ParentID == vmContent.ParentID).OrderByDescending(x => x.MeetingDate);
foreach (var obj in meetings)
{

}
```